# How to debug coldfusion orm settings and mappings

Tags: orm, coldfusion, hibernate-mapping, coldfusion-9, hbmxml

I'm having trouble with a specific ORM cfclocation not being mapped correctly. Coldfusion is checking in the cfclocation I have provided and then cacheing the mapping in a different location so that when I try to load the entity it can't find the cfc (its looking in the wrong folder).

This is only happening to one of my cfclocations. I have tried the same application on a cf10 server and it worked, and on another cf9 server where it didn't work.

So somehow its getting confused about where the cfc is located and generating a different location.

What I am wondering is how can I debug the process coldfusion is going through to cache the locations? I read the outline on orm's architecture on adobes doc pages and it mentioned coldfusion generating .hbmxml files. Where do I find these? Is there another way I can work out why coldfusion thinks a file is located somewhere else.

(I had another question similar to this which I deleted to post this one as the previous question was asking for a fix, this one is asking how to debug)

**UPDATE:**

I have turned saveMapping on and am getting the hbmxml files now. I can see that the class name is being generated incorrectly. Is there a way to manually set this? IS there a way to manually tell coldfusion what to map the location as. I have no clue why Coldfusion is mapping the location elsewhere.

**Answers to questions below**

The entityname, name, and file name are all the same.
The file is located in an area that uses a nameing convention that is the same for all of our applications which are working. In inetpub/resources/applications/[application name]/cfcs/orm.

I can dump out the array of addresses that are sent to cfclocation and it is clearly there. It has to be or the file wouldn't be detected in the first place. The ColdFusion and webroot are in different areas, but as mentioned before this works fine for all our other apps.

I have restarted the application and the ColdFusion service repeatedly while testing different things.

The folder that the hbmxml file specifies does not even exist, and never did.

Rebooting coldfusion has no effect. After messing around by adding additional mappings closer to the specific folder and then removing the mappings I eventually got the app working temporarily on my local site. but as soon as i moved it to another server it didn't work. so it seems like a 99% chance of not working

Comment: What's the CFC name, what physical file location is it at, how does that relate to the web root and the ColdFusion root, how are you referencing it, where does CF think it is, etc?

Comment: What have you tried in order to fix the problem? Were the CFCs, at one time, in the folder that the .hbmxml files specify? Have you tried calling a page that calls `ORMReload()`? Have you tried restarting ColdFusion? I have seen issues like this before and typically calling `ORMReload()` or rebooting ColdFusion solves the problem.

Comment: I added answers to your questions above